# Forcefully destroy PHP FTP Connection

Tags: php

I am downloading zip files from FTP server using PHP ftp function.I used binary and passive mode to get file.
The problem is that when I stopped the ftp operation before the completion of ftp operation(ie ftp_close() was not called) and when it was started again it shows the following Warning-

```
  ftp_login() [http://php.net/function.ftp-login]: service unavailable
  FTP connection has failed!
```

And the FTP operation was failed.I have written the following code for FTP operation.

```
$connId = ftp_connect($host);   
$loginResult = ftp_login($connId, $user, $password);    
if ((!$connId) || (!$loginResult)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    exit; 
}   
ftp_pasv($connId, true);    
if (!ftp_chdir($connId, $remoteDir))
    return false;   
if (!ftp_get($connId, $localDir.$localFile,$remoteFile,FTP_BINARY))
    return false;   
ftp_close($connId);
```

How to forcefully destroy ftp connection which has started getting files in binary mode and the connection is in passive mode?
Rebooting the machine or deleting the session cookies did not help me.What might be the possible solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebooting a machine always closes all connections made by or to that machine.

> ftp_login() [http://php.net/function.ftp-login]: service unavailable
>   FTP connection has failed!

It looks like the remote FTP server is terminating the connection before you ever get to the login step. Check that your credentials are correct and check to make sure the FTP server is operating correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This question is way old, but one I had some issues with recently. I put together a quick FTP helper class that will automatically and cleanly close connections. Hope this helps others looking for a simpler way to perform basic FTP operations.

```
//
define("SMOKE_TEST",            TRUE);
//

//  Define main FTP class.
//
class C_FTP {

    //  Connection handle.
    //
    public $h = FALSE;

    //  Close connection.
    //
    public function _Close() {
        if ($this->h) {
            ftp_close($this->h);
            $this->h = FALSE;
        }
    }

    //  Connect.
    //
    public function __construct($sDNSName) {
        $this->_Close();
        $this->h = ftp_connect($sDNSName); 
    }

    //  Destructor.
    //
    public function __destruct() {
        $this->_Close();
    }

    //  Authenticate.
    //
    public function login($sUsername = "", $sPassword = "") {
        $sError = "";
        do {
            //
            if (!$this->h) {
                $sError = "Not connected";
                break;
            }
            if (!ftp_login($this->h, $sUsername, $sPassword)) {
                $sError = "Unrecognized username or password";
                break;
            }
            ftp_pasv($this->h, TRUE); 
            //
        } while (0);
        return ($sError);
    }

    //  Change directory.
    //
    public function cd($sFolder) {
        $sError = "";
        do {
            if (!ftp_chdir($this->h, $sFolder)) {
                $sError = "Unable to change directory";
                break;
            }
        } while (0);
        return ($sError);
    }

    //  List files in current directory.
    //
    public function dir(&$aFiles) {
        $sError = "";
        do {
            if (($aFiles = ftp_nlist($this->h, ".")) === FALSE) {
                $sError = "Unable to list files in current directory";
                break;
            }
        } while (0);
        return ($sError);
    }

    //  Get file from remote site into specified local file.
    //
    public function get($sLocalFile, $sRemoteFilename) {
        $sError = "";
        do {
            if (!ftp_get($this->h, $sLocalFile, $sRemoteFilename, FTP_BINARY)) {
                $sError = "Could not perform file get";
                break;
            }               
        } while (0);
        return ($sError);
    }

    //  Put file from remote site into current directory.
    //
    public function put($sLocalFile, $sRemoteFilename) {
        $sError = "";
        do {
            if (!ftp_put($this->h, $sRemoteFilename, $sLocalFile, FTP_BINARY)) {
                $sError = "Could not perform file put";
                break;
            }               
        } while (0);
        return ($sError);
    }

//  ...end FTP class.
//  
}


//  If we are running a stand-alone test of this class,
//      set SMOKE_TEST to TRUE and invoke from CLI.
//      For example: c:\php\php C_FTP.php
//
if (SMOKE_TEST) {
    //
    function IsError($sMessage) {
        if (strlen($sMessage)) {
            echo("Error: ".$sMessage);
            return (true);
        } else {
            return (false);
        }
    }
    //
    do {
        //
        $aFiles = array();
        //
        $cFTP = new C_FTP(FTP_DNS_NAME);
        if (IsError($cFTP->login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASSWORD)))          { break; }
        if (IsError($cFTP->cd("Env")))                              { break; }
        if (IsError($cFTP->get("foo.txt", "SomeRemoteFile.txt")))   { break; }
        if (IsError($cFTP->dir($aFiles)))                           { break; }
        var_dump($aFiles);
        //
    } while (0);
    //
}
?>
```

Please note that this forces passive mode for data transfer, so if you need active, you'll need to adjust accordingly.